Is it posible to use Hyperledger Caliper with Hyperledger Fabric v3.0.0?
As you know, Hyperledger Fabric v3.0.0 has been recently released. I want to use and test it with Hyperledger Caliper. I looked into many resources, but all of them describe using Caliper for pre-Hyperledger Fabric v3.0.0. Is it possible to use Hyperledger Caliper with Hyperledger Fabric current versions (v3.0.0 and later) to evaluate the network? Has anyone tried it before?

I haven't tried it personally, so take this with a grain of salt. However, Caliper can use the Fabric Gateway client API as its binding for testing Fabric. See the Caliper documentation. The Fabric Gateway client API is the current supported client API for all versions of Fabric from v2.4 onwards, which includes Fabric v3.
While no longer supported, the legacy client SDKs for Fabric (which Caliper can also use) should still work with Fabric v3 using Raft consensus. The legacy SDKs will not work with Fabric v3 using a BFT ordering service. Only the Fabric Gateway client API supports Fabric with a BFT ordering service. Since Caliper can use the Fabric Gateway client API, it should also work with Fabric v3 using BFT consensus.
